# Logging input and log file strings

Tags: performance, c, strings, logging

This is a piece of C89 code testing a function titled `logging_function()`, which takes two arguments and uses them to log a bit of information.

In this case, the first argument to the function is the string to be logged, and the second argument is a string holding a path in a filesystem to a log file. The first string is printed, with a timestamp, to stdout and the log file.

**Note:** although yes input on the `main()` function would be wonderful, I'd love it if you gave thoughts on the function `logging_function()` itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1

typedef struct tm tm;

int logging_function(char input_string[], char log_file_string[])
{
    /*Initializations.*/
    char output_string[32767];
    FILE* log_file_stream;
    time_t current_time_epoch_format;
    tm* current_time_calandar_format;

    /*Creating timestamp in output string, amending first argument to output string, and logging.*/
    if ((strlen(input_string) + 23) > 32767) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if ((current_time_epoch_format = time(&current_time_epoch_format)) == -1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if ((current_time_calandar_format = localtime(&current_time_epoch_format)) == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (strftime(output_string, 23, "[%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S] ", current_time_calandar_format) != 22) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if ((log_file_stream = fopen(log_file_string, "a")) == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (printf("%s\n", strcat(output_string, input_string)) < 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (fprintf(log_file_stream, "%s\n", output_string) < 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (fclose(log_file_stream) == EOF) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /*Initializations.*/
    int EXIT_CODE;

    /*Print the returned integer from logging_function and exit.*/
    printf("%d\n", (EXIT_CODE = logging_function(argv[1], argv[2])));
    exit(EXIT_CODE);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are defined by `stdlib.h`. I think you need not define them.

You can add the `const` qualifier to arguments of `logging_function()`. Those strings are not going to be modified.

You can call `fprintf()` twice, once with the `strftime()` output and then with `input_string[]` and avoid the `strcat()`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I like all those `if statements` lined up like that it makes it hard to read. I have tried to make it more readable (at the end). Weather it works is a matter of opinion so I would not say mine is any better just an alternative.

You also need to watch open()/close() on a file. You should always call close() even if the other functions fail. Otherwise there is potential for you to run out of file descriptors (though unlikely). In short it is a resorce leak and that can be a problem.

```
if ((log_file_stream = fopen(log_file_string, "a")) == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
if (printf("%s\n", strcat(output_string, input_string)) < 1) {
    fclose(log_file_stream);  // Need to close the fstream
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (fprintf(log_file_stream, "%s\n", output_string) < 1) {
    fclose(log_file_stream);  // Need to close the fstream
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (fclose(log_file_stream) == EOF) return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Your large number of if statements could be reduced (without reducing readability). I would not go to the extreme of putting it all in one if statement but you can definately combine a few.

```
if (   ((strlen(input_string) + 23) > 32767)
    || ((current_time_epoch_format = time(&current_time_epoch_format)) == -1)
    || ((current_time_calandar_format = localtime(&current_time_epoch_format)) == NULL)
    || (strftime(output_string, 23, "[%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S] ", current_time_calandar_format) != 22)
    || (strcat(output_string, input_string) != output_string)
   )
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

printf("%s\n", output_string); // If this fails I am still going to try and print
                               // to the log file.
                               // I will consider it success if the file printing
                               // works correctly even if this fails.

int result = 0;
if ((log_file_stream = fopen(log_file_string, "a")) != NULL)
{
    int printOk = fprintf(log_file_stream, "%s\n", output_string) == 1;
    int closeOK = (fclose(log_file_stream) == 0);

    result = printOk && closeOk;
}
return result != 0
          ? EXIT_SUCCESS
          : EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Some note on your code as it stands:

- unnecessary redefinition of EXIT_*
- unnecessary typedef of struct tm
- your parameters should be `const`
- `localtime` is not thread safe - better to use `localtime_r`
- printing of the message to the `output_string` is unnecessary.  Better to print directly to stdout/file than to an intermediate buffer.
- the buffer is also too large to safely put on the stack (in particular in an embedded
  system).
- variable names are much too long
- the code is difficult to read

Also, perhaps you should consider the design more carefully.

How will you use the function?  Do you really want everything logged to a
  file **and** to `stdout`?  These are activities that I would argue should be
  kept separate.  At times you might want to log to a file.  If no file is
  specified you might want to log to `stdout` instead; or even to `stderr`
  depending upon the nature of the messages.  So one function to do everything
  seems a bad design.

Then there is the question of error handling.  You have handled all sorts of
  errors without distinguishing between those which are likely and those which
  are not, and without considering what should be done if they occur.  Let's
  look at what is likely to fail first:

1. The most likely is that `fopen()` fails because the log file path doesn't
   exist or is protected.
2. Once you've opened the file successfully, it is unlikely that closing it
   will fail unless you pass `fclose()` the wrong pointer or maybe the
   preceding `fprintf()` failed.
3. `fprintf(stdout)` might fail if `stdout` is for some reason no longer
   open.
4. `fprintf(file)` could fail if the filesystem has become full
5. your calls to `time()`, `localtime()` or `strftime()` might conceivably
   fail but failure is really very unlikely.

How should you respond to each faiure?

For 1, 2, 3 and 4, propagate the error and use `perror` to print the error
  to `stderr` if and when appropriate.  But note that failure 1 is most likely at the start of the program, so it makes sense to log a starting message from `main()` early on, with an exit on failure.

Do you need to handle failure 5 in the same way?  It is a remote possibilty,
  most likely during testing when you have not got the strftime format
  correct.  Unless you consider the fault serious, just omit the time in case
  of failure (but ensure that the subsequent code does not fail as a result).

For what it is worth, here is how I might rewrite your function. There is a `log_msg` function that logs to any stream and a log_to_file that logs to a file using log_msg.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static int
log_msg(FILE *f, const char *msg)
{
    time_t when = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm;
    char buf[20];
    localtime_r(&when, &tm);
    if (strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm) == 0) {
        buf[0] = '\0';
    }
    if (fprintf(f, "[%s] %s\n", buf, msg) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static int
log_to_file(const char *msg, const char *filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "a");
    if (!f) {
        return -1;
    }
    int ret = log_msg(f, msg);
    if (fclose(f) != 0) {
        ret = -1;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        const char *filename = argv[1];
        if (log_to_file("Hello, just testing", filename) < 0) {
            perror(filename);
        }
    } else {
        if (log_msg(stdout, "Hello, just testing") < 0) {
            perror("stdout");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((log_file_stream = fopen(log_file_string, "a")) == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
if (printf("%s\n", strcat(output_string, input_string)) < 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
if (fprintf(log_file_stream, "%s\n", output_string) < 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
if (fclose(log_file_stream) == EOF) return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

You leak `log_file_stream` if any of the lines between the `fopen` and the `fclose` fail.

There are several ways around this.  In C (which does not have exceptions or [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII)), the best way around this is to avoid early `return` statements when there's something to clean up.  (Allocation, file handle, lock being held, etc.)

For example you could do (just meant as a quick sketch):

```
FILE *log_file_stream = NULL;
int status = 0;

if (!status && (log_file_stream = fopen(log_file_string, "a")) == NULL) status = EXIT_FAILURE;
if (!status && printf("%s\n", strcat(output_string, input_string)) < 1) status = EXIT_FAILURE;
if (!status && fprintf(log_file_stream, "%s\n", output_string) < 1) status = EXIT_FAILURE;

// Close the file if it is non-NULL.
//
if (log_file_stream)
   fclose(log_file_stream);

return status;
```

The key benefit is that this `fclose` call runs regardless of success or failure, similar to a `finally` block or a destructor in RAII.  You can add more `if (!status && /* ... */)` blocks at will and you won't have to add redundant cleanup code.

Another way to do this is to use `goto` (if you are not morally opposed to it for silly reasons - it actually works well in C code for this specific purpose and you'll find it all over large projects, including *nix kernels.)

```
   FILE *log_file_stream = NULL;
   int status = 0;

   if ((log_file_stream = fopen(log_file_string, "a")) == NULL) goto error;
   if (printf("%s\n", strcat(output_string, input_string)) < 1) goto error;
   if (fprintf(log_file_stream, "%s\n", output_string) < 1) goto error;

   cleanup:
      // Close the file if it is non-NULL.
      //
      if (log_file_stream)
         fclose(log_file_stream);

      return status;

   error:
      status = EXIT_FAILURE;
      goto cleanup;
```

This gives you the benefit of not having to tediously check `status` again and again.

---

**Update on 2nd reading**

I don't like some of the repeated buffer size constants here, for example `strlen(input_string) + 23 > 32767` ... how weird to write out `32767` instead of `sizeof(output_string)`, which would allow you to change the size without having to change it in two places.

Taking `strlen()` (an O(n) operation) to perform the size check is also a bit odd.  One common idiom in C code is to just optimistically start storing characters in the output buffer, and the moment you detect that you don't have enough space, ***that's*** when you return the error.  (Think of an implementation of `strncpy(dst, src, n)` which has something like `while (*src && n) { *dst++ = *src++; --n; }` at its core.)  Looking at your code though it doesn't seem like using that idiom directly will be convenient, but you can start using standard string functions in a way that will be more consistent with that.  Maybe you should make the `strftime` call write into a stack-allocated temporary buffer (and again, please pass something derived from `sizeof` as the size parameter, rather than writing an integer constant size twice), then feed the results into `snprintf(output_buffer, sizeof(output_buffer), /* ... */)`, which will take this approach.

Answer (score 1):

For one... I don't see any check of  `argc == 3`  to make sure the two arguments were actually passed on the command line.

As to others, well, I'd have to study it some more (and frankly I'm not so sure I want to look that hard right now).

Comment: I actually had a line for that, but I deleted it during testing. ._. Meh, its irrelavent as the main focus should be on the function logging_function. Here, lemme edit my post to reflect such.

Comment: Okay, also sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Sorry, didn't meant to offend.  If anything I couldn't find else obviously wrong and it'd take some work to find it (that's a good thing)!